# How to Choose Design Specs for Passive and Active filters

Tags: operational-amplifier, filter, homework

I have a work to do about the active filters, but the requirements looks to me repetitive and redundant, but beyond what it seems to me, it has to be done.
Perhaps is a bit boring, because I would have to repeat the info several times.
Let's say, I understand there is 4 basic types: low pass, high pass, band pass and band reject, each one can have a Butterworth response, etc.
Then the info should be the same over and over again?

The index is:

- By component
  Passive
  Active
- By signal
  Digital
  Analogic
- By bandwidth
- By response (isn't it define in bandwidth?)
- By roll-off (again, isn't this in bandwidth?)
- By bandwidth and slope
- By response (again?)
  Chebyschev
  Butterworth
  Bessel

How suggest me to explain the information avoiding to be repetitive and write useful info in each section?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What does "By signal Digital Analogic" mean? I suggest that you study a book about filters as you're asking very basic questions, example: *By response (isnt it define in bandwith?)* No, the same BW doesn't mean that the response is the same. *By roll-off (again, isnt this in bandwith?)* again no. Filters with the same BW can have a different roll-off and that means a different response.

Comment: I was thinking the same, Im missing something; "By signal Digital Analogic"  its a typo. Thanks for the support.

Comment: Take a look at [Analog's FilterWizard](https://tools.analog.com/en/filterwizard/) and [Linear Tech's FilterCad3](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=filtercad+3+download&t=opera&ia=web) for an easy way to visualize the parameters of these filters.

Comment: @rdtsc, many thanks , I will.

Comment: "By filter order"should be on that list; the order of a filter is closely related to its rolloff rate.

Comment: @user_1818839, and yet this  was not added to the description.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I made a little summary using TI's portable Filter  Designer.

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

In general the highest Q determines the need for tighter tolerances, but this software allows you to choose any error tolerance for all R's or all C's and see the difference.

Also the GBW of a filter is not just the unity gain * BW but rather  the required GBW of any filter for the highest Q stage is ;

$$GBW = Q^2 * A_V * BW_{-3dB}$$

[image]

[www.Falstad.com/AFILTER](http://www.Falstad.com/AFILTER) site also has a quick Filter Design for both Active and Passive but does not perform tolerances or impedance optimization for low current Op Amps but allows an interactive slider for Spectrum , Cutoff and Ripple.  It also does log/linear , phase and Pole-Zero Plots.

Comment: Thanks, it help me a lot!!!